# How to change badge number when user receive notification in background mode

Tags: ios, swift

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    /*
        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
        if let count = aps["badge"] as? Int {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 2
        }
    */

    let custom = notification["custom"] as! [String: AnyObject]

    if let home = custom["a"]!["home"] as? String, home == "1" {
        incrementBadgeNumberBy(badgeNumberIncrement: 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In General Application Badge is set from push notification payload.

Payload example:

```
{
   “aps” : {
      “badge” : 9
   },
}
```

or

You also can set badge using

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 3
```